# Tikz node label position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this tikz graph but the label of node A is covered by the edge. Is there a way to position it in the right corner of the node?

```
  \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}, scale=0.8,transform shape] 
\node[main , fill=black, label=left:{\small $B$}] (1) [] {}; 
  \node[main ,  label=right:{\small $A$}] (2) [ right of=1] {}; 
  \node[main , label=left:{\small $B$}] (1) [left  of=2] {}; 
\node[main , fill=black,label=above:{\small $C$}] (3) [right  of=2] {}; 
 \node[main, label=below:{\small $C^*$}] (4) [ below of=3] {};
 \node[main, label=below:{\small $R_C$}]  (5) [ below of=2]{}; 
 \node[main , label=above:{\small $B^*$}] (6) [above  of=1] {}; 
  \node[main , label=above:{\small $R_B$}] (7) [above  of=2] {}; 
\draw[->] (2) -- (1); 
\draw[->] (2) -- (3); 
\draw[->] (7) -- (6); 
  \draw[->] (2) -- (5); 
    \draw[->] (2) -- (7);
    \draw[->] (3) -- (4); 
\draw[->] (1) -- (6);
\draw[->] (5) -- (4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Also is there a way to make the graph curvy? like is there other packages that produces curvy graphs?

Comment: Put a complete code! In any case the answer of Your question is:
'label=above right:{\small $A$}]'.

Comment: Welcome. Please check [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.10.2). The label position (that's the part before `:`) allows for any angle and you can also just change the `anchor` of the label independetly of the label position. You can also adjust the [`label distance`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./tikz/label:distance).

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro, please consider to write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not complete. In any case  the answer for Your question is a little correction to Your code:
`label=above right:{\small $A$}]`.

Complete working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,font=\small, node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}, scale=0.8,transform shape] 
            \node[main , fill=black, label=left:{\small $B$}] (1) [] {}; 
            \node[main ,  label=above right:{\small $A$}] (2) [ right of=1] {}; 
            \node[main , label=left:{\small $B$}] (1) [left  of=2] {}; 
            \node[main , fill=black,label=above:{\small $C$}] (3) [right  of=2] {}; 
            \node[main, label=below:{\small $C^*$}] (4) [ below of=3] {};
            \node[main, label=below:{\small $R_C$}]  (5) [ below of=2]{}; 
            \node[main , label=above:{\small $B^*$}] (6) [above  of=1] {}; 
            \node[main , label=above:{\small $R_B$}] (7) [above  of=2] {}; 
            \draw[->] (2) -- (1); 
            \draw[->] (2) -- (3); 
            \draw[->] (7) -- (6); 
            \draw[->] (2) -- (5); 
            \draw[->] (2) -- (7);
            \draw[->] (3) -- (4); 
            \draw[->] (1) -- (6);
            \draw[->] (5) -- (4); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked great.

Comment: @Moh You are welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small variation of nice @Raffaele Santoro answer (+1).

For your image i would define two nodes style, one for black dot, one for white, define nodes' labels stale by `every label/.append style = ...`, defineg arrows style by `every edge/.style and for node positioning use` positioning `library`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
   node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
                   thick,
                   %on grid,
bdot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.8pt,
                           label=#1, node contents = {}},
wdot/.style = {bdot=#1, fill=white},
every label/.append style = {node distance=2pt, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize},
 every edge/.style = {draw, - Straight Barb}
                        ]
\node (1) [bdot=left:$B$];
\node (2) [wdot=above right:$A$, right=of 1];
\node (3) [bdot=above:$C$,  right=of 2];
\node (4) [wdot=below:$C^*$,below=of 3];
\node (5) [wdot=below:$R_C$,below=of 2];
\node (6) [wdot=above:$B^*$,above=of 1];
\node (7) [wdot=above:$R_B$,above=of 2];
\draw   (2) edge (1)    (2) edge (3) 
        (7) edge (6)    (2) edge (5) 
        (2) edge (7)    (3) edge (4) 
        (1) edge (6)    (5) edge (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]